# PSpice MATLAB/Simulink Interface for Orcad 16.5

Tags: matlab, simulator, simulink, pspice, orcad

I am using Matlab 7 SLPS version 2.65 and Orcad 16.5 but I am getting the following error when I try to execute the sample program. Attaching the screenshots Any help will be Highly appreciated.

[image: The circuit]

[image: The Error]

[image: The block that is giving the error]

Comment: The error is related to SLPS, not MATLAB. It's probably got something to do with how you set up the block.

Comment: Is my version of SLPS compatible with the version of Orcad I had replaced the dll to fix one issue.

Comment: That was what I was trying to say: I don't know anything about Orcad or SLPS and I don't think many people will on SO. It's a fairly niche software, you'd be better off contacting their technical support or asking on their forums.

Comment: Thanks @am304 the only reason I asked here was I could not find help from anywhere else i.e. from Mathworks Cadence the official owner of SLPS they no longer support SLPS 2.65 and though my Orcad 16.5 and Matlab are registered the SLPS was downloaded from a china based website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there are multiple versions of SLPS available in your system, the path of the recent version should be set higher in the set path. This error is due to the configuration mismatch between different versions of SLPS.